# Hinder Moq to mock abstract classes without default constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I like to use the `DefaultMock.Mock` behavior of Moq. Now I have the problem, that in the so mocked object hierarchy one object from an abstract class without a default constructor. When somebody now tries to get this object, I get an exception. Is there a way to work around this behavior?

An short example:

```
//The abstract class
public abstract class Abstract
{
    protected Abstract(string foo)
    {
    }
}

//The mocked interface
public interface ITestClass
{
    Abstract Abstract { get; }
}

//The mock
internal class TestClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Mock<ITestClass> testMock = new Mock<ITestClass> {DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock};
        Abstract foo = testMock.Object.Abstract;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the line `Abstract foo = testMock.Object.Abstract;` the exception is the following:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Can not instantiate proxy of class: UsedLibrary.Abstract.
Could not find a parameterless constructor.
Parametername: constructorArguments
  Source=Castle.Core
  ParamName=constructorArguments
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Compilable, Example](http://sscce.org), please?

Comment: You should also include details of what the exception is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround should be something like this:

```
Mock<ITestClass> testMock = new Mock<ITestClass> {DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock};
testMock.SetupGet(p => p.Abstract).Returns(new Abstract("foo"));
Abstract foo = testMock.Object.Abstract;
```

But FIRST !!! You can't create instance of an abstract class so you should implement a class which derives from abstract one. Code should looks like:

```
testMock.SetupGet(p => p.Abstract).Returns(new InstanceWhichDerivesFromAbstract("foo"));
```

You should provide an implementation for Abstract class

```
public class InstanceWhichDerivesFromAbstract : Abstract
{
//implementation
}
```

Comment: Why not just provide a mock of the abstract class and call it a day?  Also, SetupGet... nice.

Comment: I know this possibility. Only thing that is really annoying with this solution is, that in the real example the abstract object is somewhere in the third or forth level of a mocked hierarchy. It is a pain to do this.